# The number of permutations with k fixed points

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, permutations, fixed-point-theorems, derangements

Could someone help me please with this problem? I don't even know how to start it.

For 1$\leq$k$\leq$n, find the number of permutations $\theta$ $\in$ $S_n$ that have exactly k fixed points.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: **Hint :** Such a permutation is given by the choice of the $k$ fixed points, and by the choice of a *derangement* of the $n-k$ other elements.

Comment: It could be really interesting working on the function "type" $t$ such that for $\theta \in S_n$ (you can always write $\theta$ as a composition of disjoint cycles $\theta=C_1 \dots C_k$) you have $t(\theta)=(n_1,n_2, \dots , n_k)$, where $n_1, \dots , n_k$ are the lenghts of the disjoint cycles that form $\theta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the case $k=0$, this is the problem of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

For $k > 1$, after first choosing $k$ members of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to be the fixed points, you then want a derangement of the remaining $n-k$.